# Solving implicit integral equation

Tags: integration, implicit

This is my first post, and I am looking for some help in using Matlab or any easy way to solve the following equation.
[This shows how the equation would look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SpK0.png)
Below is my code in Matlab:

```
Delta_T=5;
T_b=373;
rho_l=958;
rho_g=0.05956;
C_l=4217;
C_g=2029;
k=0.680;
L=2257E3;
R(:,:)=zeros;
pi=3.1415;
beta_0=1;

beta=fsolve((rho_l*C_l*Delta_T)/(rho_g(L+(C_l-C_g)*Delta_T))*
(1/integral((@ksi)exp(-beta_g^2*((1-ksi)^(-2)-2*(1-(rho_g/rho_l))*ksi-
1),0,1))),beta_0);
beta_g=sqrt(beta/2);
```